# Is there a good article/document describing how IdentityServer4 data tables and columns work together?

Tags: identityserver4

I have successfully setup IdentityServer by following quickstart samples. But what I am still unclear is how the IdentityServer data tables and columns work. I have about 30 tables created along the way (some of those are ASP.Net Core Identity related tables) and they work fine. But the IdentityServer online doc doesn't seem to contain a good detailed description about how they work together. Can someone point me to some good resource explaining the internal work?
[image]

Comment: I believe these tables are considered internal implementation so there is no any public documentation. So it's the question why you need to know their structure as they are not supposed to work directly with. By the way, AspNet* tables are parts of ASP.NET Identity, not IdentityServer4

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I just want to understand the concepts. such as which table(s) play what role (configuration? operation? etc.) and in what way. What, for instance, "ClientCorsOrigins" mean and what is the table for? Related to these type of understanding, if I want to associate my Users to Clients, what should I do? I guess I can expand my Users table to add a ClientID field, but is that the right way to do it?...

Comment: I think I might have found what I am looking for... it may just be spread out across the IndentityServer doc but not in one place. It would be nice if they had a data model and detailed description all in one place and then link them back to each topic sections.

Comment: Clients and Users are two different entities. They shouldn't be linked in any way. AspNet Identity should handle the users and IDS should handle the applications (clients). IE: I want to use Postman to call my API. Postman is my client (dbo.Clients), my API is my scope (dbo.ApiScopes), and Postman has access to my API (dbo.ClientScopes). What you pass in to IDS (authorize or token) depends on your grant type. Another IE: I log into my web app and want to authorize a view. My web app is the client, what that client has access to are its scopes and me as a user is authenticated via Net Identity

Comment: Thanks GH DevOps for the explanation, that's very helpful! Sounds like using Clients table to represent my customer companies is a bad idea, and that makes sense. But what I need here is to have a data object representing our customer companies and tie users to them. What should I do for that? Is there any data objects from IDS that's designed for this kind of functions? Or maybe I just need to add a table "Customers" to the mix and add a CustomerID field in AspNetUsers table to tie users to companies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the columns and tables maps directly 1-1 with the configuration objects in IdentityServer. Including the Client and the Resource types. However, as some of the types are pretty complex, they are normalized across several tables. You can also look at the source of the IdentityServer storage library to see how the database is mapped to those objects.

Comment: Thanks Tore. Just accepted you answer. What I am really looking for is an advice about how to link my costumers (companies that my IdentityServer serves) to each individual users (stored in AspNetUsers table) of the costumers. I am now leaning toward using ClientID in Client table to represent a customer, then add a "ClientID" column in AspNetUsers to cross reference it. But I am not sure if that's the right way to do it, or maybe there are other data tables/columns are designed for that purpose. If you could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could also add a Userclaim that maps to the customerId , that is one way to achieve it.  But its hard to generalize as it depends on your needs.